# Google Apps Script shown incorrect values

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Script to update a Google spreadsheet.
The Apps script is taking the follower count for Twitter pages. 
I am using below formula for the same

I have used [this](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/import-social-media-statistics/) URL for reference

```
  cell.setValue('=IMPORTXML(\"'+url+'\","//a[@data-nav=\'followers\']/span[3]")');
```

Basically we are doing a kind of scraping here to extract the count values. The above code is looking for  `anchor` tag with value for `data-nav`     as  `followers`  and taking the text inside the 3rd `span` tag . When I inspected the page in browser , the value shown in the third `span` tag was 100 (for example).
But the value picked by appscript is higher than that (like 101 or 102) . 
  I thought it was due to caching , and we even used random numbers to avoid that , but even that didn't work.The  details for that was found [here](https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/207238327-Using-Google-Sheets-IMPORTXML-function-to-display-data-in-Geckoboard#automaticupdate)

Can somebody have a look into this ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem* or *error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: _"Can somebody have a look into this?"_ In a word, no. This is not some kind of free consultancy service. But seeing that you've quoted two sources, I advise you to grab a copy of Ben Collins spreadsheet and adapt his formula. His works, GeckoBoard doesn't. Simple as that!